# optimized code for conversion to nullable integer

Tags: c#, integer, nullable

I am using below code to convert a string value to integer and set in nullable integer variable only if value is greater then zeor '0'.

NOTE: its working fine but i want experts advice to optimize it and make it a library function.

```
if (txtdownload.Text.Trim() != "")
{
  int i = 0;
  int.TryParse(txtdownload.Text, out i);
  if (i > 0)
  {
       pad.Noofdownload = i;//Noofdownload is a property on nullable integer
  }
}
```

Please help to create a Optimized library function (common function), which i can use for all such a conversion.

Thanks a lot.

NOTE: i have created below library function but its not working for properties as we can't pass properties as a ref.

```
 public static void  getValueFromTextBoxInNullable(string  srctext,ref  int? dest)
        {
            if (srctext.Trim() != "")
            {
                int j = 0;
                int.TryParse(srctext , out j);
                if (j > 0)
                {
                    dest = j;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This should be migrated to codereview.stackexchange.com as there is no problem, just a desire for a better version. (I realised this after I answered it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an extension method that should do the job:

```
public static int? ToNullableInt(this string source)
{
    var i = 0;
    return int.TryParse(source, out i) ? (int?)i : null;
}
```